# WSO2 Identity Server not authentication against tenant ldap store

Tags: authentication, wso2

I have configured my WSO2 Identity server with a tenant. Then I logged in as tenant admin and configured a Read Write LDAP userstore for that tenant. I also configured a Service Provider against that tenant.

The problem that I am facing is that while I try to login to my service, the user authentication against the tenant LDAP store is not working. I have verified the password using ldap utility and ensured that it is the right password. Also if I login to the Administrative console of WSO2 Identity Server and change the password using the admin console the service provider login will work for sometime. (I guess till the next sync). I have also ensured that the password hashing mechanism (in optional properties of the tenant user store) is same as that in the LDAP user store. (Both are set to SHA).

Is there anything that I am doing wrong with my configuration? If somebody can point me in the right direction it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm whether you can login to WSO2 Identity Server as this tenant user. If this is also not working, we have a problem in user store configuration in tenant. Will be able to help you if you can submit the error log and user store configuration.

If above is working and it's only through the SP that you can't access, please double check whether the tenant tenant domain is passed in correctly.

Comment: As a tenant user i cannot login to WSO2 identity server. But that is coz the user doesnot have admin privileges. If i update the password of the tenant user via the wso2 console then i am able to login. So the issue (i guess) is that the SHA encoded password verification is not happening from WSO2. Any hints as to why it is happening. In the LDAP the password encryption is set to SHA.

Comment: A user only requires 'login' privileges to login to Identity Server. No admin privileges are required, just to login.

Comment: right.... so the core problem that i am facing is that once i configure the userstore (as an external LDAP system) i can see that the users in the ldap are shown in the WSO2 identity server. However if i try to login with that user it says invalid credentials even though the credentials are right. But if i go into the WSO2 identiry server and reset the password for that usre then i am able to login. any ideas as to what could be the issue there?